# When fitting a generalised additive model, how to choose how much to smooth?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, degrees-of-freedom, mgcv, smoothing, regression-strategies

When fitting a GAM, is there a rule (of thumb) for deciding if $k$ (max number of degrees of freedom for a spline) is large enough or not? How much should edf be below $k'$? And is that an absolute difference (e.g. 1) or rather a relative difference (e.g. 10% of $k'$)?

(I am aware of the different methods to optimise k such as increasing $k$ and checking again etc., but I am generally interested in getting a feeling for when it's actually necessary or rather acceptable to keep $k$ low [when the aim is to have smooths as non-wiggly as possible])

Example:

```
Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                   k'     edf k-index             p-value    
s(A)             6.00    4.95    0.97               0.010 ** 
s(B)             4.00    2.81    1.01               0.700    
s(C)             4.00    3.97    0.86 <0.0000000000000002 ***
s(D)             5.00    3.95    0.83 <0.0000000000000002 ***
s(E)             5.00    4.81    0.82 <0.0000000000000002 ***
s(F)             5.00    3.89    0.82 <0.0000000000000002 ***
s(G)             4.00    3.83    0.98               0.055 .  
te(H,I ,J)      48.00   38.12    0.73 <0.0000000000000002 ***
```